Opening a file in three splits of specific sizes from the command line
I have a significant number of similarly-structured LaTeX source files to edit, and find it convenient to use three splits:

one for the section of the file that contains a verse, which is normally only two lines, but I keep the corresponding split four lines big,
the second split contains the section of the file with my edition of a Sanskrit commentary on the verse,
and in the third split I work on my annotated English translation of the verse.

The sizes of the second and third split do not matter too much, but in the session that's now running the second split is 27 lines and the third is 15 lines.
So upon opening my file, I will

twice use the command :sp and then
resize the topmost split to about four lines, typing many times ctrl+w-, with a significant risk of me typing just ctrl+-, decreasing the font size of the terminal.

Now I could open the file in three equal-size splits from the command line vim -o file.tex file.tex file.tex, around which I could write a bash wrapper so I have to give the file name only once.
But is there a way of specifying the size of the splits from the command line?
Thinking about it, probably it will be better to just record the commands I use to set up the splits to my convenience in a macro, and execute it as the first thing I do when I open a file of that kind.

Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Building on Vivian's answer, if you place the commands you need in a script (say, Session.vim), than you can use -S to source it at the command line (-S automatically uses a Session.vim that it finds, but you can pass any file name you like for it to read and execute).
So with Session.vim containing
split
resize 4
wincmd j
split
resize 27
wincmd j

I think vim file.tex -S ought to work.

I would open the file:
vim file.tex

And execute the commands:
split
resize 4
wincmd j
split
resize 27
wincmd j

You could do it in one go:
vim grr.vim -c "split|resize 4|wincmd j|split|resize 27|wincmd j"


That's almost it. The next thing I would do after that, or in between switching to the lower splits, would be to navigate to the proper positions in the file, but maybe that cannot be done so easily. Or would something like /\\stanza\s*$ inside vim, i.e. a search for a regular expression, be possible using the syntax expected by -c?

You could do: execute "normal /\\\\stanza\\s*\<CR>" .

Not quite getting me where I want yet. Furthermore, this gets complicated with the two layers of quotation marks and backslashes, and the switch to normal mode. Probably better to record a macro from inside vim, save it, load and execute it. But of course the macro syntax is also rather cryptic.

On Windows this one seems to work: gVim grr.tex -c "execute 'normal /stanza'.""\<CR>""" but on Linux where the argument passing convention are different you probably need to adapt :-|

I'm indeed on Linux. For my first split, the search expression needs to match a line containing nothing but \stanza (and perhaps a bit of syntactically irrelevant whitespace at the end of the line). I am now at a point where it apparently went to the first line containing \stanza but as part of a variable \stanzaindentbase, which is why I had ended the expression with an optional whitespace of undefined length and an end-of-line ($).
